# Appium for iOS using Eclipse

Tags: javascript, ios, eclipse, appium, swipe

```
public static boolean swipeToDirection_iOS_XCTest(MobileElement el, String direction) {
        try {
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            HashMap<String, String> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
            if (direction.equals("d")) {
                swipeObject.put("direction", "down");
            } else if (direction.equals("u")) {
                swipeObject.put("direction", "up");
            } else if (direction.equals("l")) {
                swipeObject.put("direction", "left");
            } else if (direction.equals("r")) {
                swipeObject.put("direction", "right");
            }
            swipeObject.put("element", el.getId());
            js.executeScript("mobile:swipe", swipeObject);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

> I am trying to run this piece of code and it doesn't recognize the
>   driver where I have created an object of javascript executor. As far
>   as I know, it is part of the syntax but it shows the error: "driver
>   cannot be resolved as a variable".
>
> ```
> I have already invoked the following:
> import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
> ```
>
> Anyone can help with it?

Comment: Have you initialize appiumDriver?

Comment: A friend helped. The driver is basically the iOS driver instance that we create.

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped. The driver is basically the iOS driver instance that we create.